# Ruby on Rails NameError: uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just set up a new migration and model relationships, and in console when testing the relationship between tables I get the following error: NameError: uninitialized constant.

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong?

Thank you

Edit:

Here's the error

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Profile::ProfileNotification
  from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:105:in `const_missing'
  from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:2199:in `compute_type'
  from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'
  from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:2195:in `compute_type'
  from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:156:in `send'
  from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:156:in `klass'
  from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:187:in `quoted_table_name'
  from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:97:in `construct_sql'
  from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:21:in `initialize'
  from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1300:in `new'
  from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1300:in `profile_notifications'
  from (irb):3
```

Code from the ProfileNotification migration:

```
class CreateProfileNotifications < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :profile_notifications do |t|
      t.integer :profile_id, :null => false
      t.integer :notification_id, :null => false
      t.string :notification_text
      t.boolean :checked, :default => false
      t.boolean :update_reply, :default => false
      t.boolean :opinion_reply, :default => false
      t.boolean :message_reply, :default => false
      t.boolean :pm, :default => false
      t.boolean :accepted_friend, :default => false
      t.boolean :accepted_supporter, :default => false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :profile_notifications
  end
end
```

Comment: You're going to have to give us a bit more to go on... model source perhaps?

Comment: I have a table called profiles, and I created a new one called ProfileNotifications. There's a one-to-many relationship set up between the table. In the profile model I have :has_many :profile_notifications, and in the ProfileNotification model I have :belongs_to :profile. In console I type user = Profile.find(1), and then user.profile_notifications and I get the error message posted above.

Comment: Is the class in the model ProfileNotifications or ProfileNotification? In your comment above you have it listed as both.

Comment: the migration is named CreateProfileNotifications

Answer (score 28):

Well, I figured out the problem. When I was running ruby script/generate model, I was typing ruby script/generate model ProfileNotifications. When I typed ruby script/generate model ProfileNotification (singular) it worked. Naming conventions kill me. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Models are singular, controllers are plural, table names are plural. Generators can be a bit of a crutch, I would recommend getting familiar with the conventions Rails expects you to follow, or you'll have a hell of a time getting this to work :)

Comment: By the way, I tried to fix it by editing the model, but it still didn't work. I guess you have to rollback the migration, delete all the files created, and regenerate the migration. The good news is that it tells you all the files created.

Answer (score 3):

It's breaking because you're referencing `Profile::ProfileNotification` which doesn't exist.

Rails considers this a model named `ProfileNotification` located in the `Profile` namespace, but your comment suggests that `Profile` is another model class and not a namespace.

Based on the migration you have posted, I think you're confused about the Rails naming convention for one-to-many relationships. Here's how I think it's supposed to look:

```
class CreateNotifications < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :notifications do |t|
      t.references :profile
      t.text :body
      t.boolean :checked, :default => false
      t.boolean :update_reply, :default => false
      t.boolean :opinion_reply, :default => false
      t.boolean :message_reply, :default => false
      t.boolean :pm, :default => false
      t.boolean :accepted_friend, :default => false
      t.boolean :accepted_supporter, :default => false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :notifications
  end
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notifications
end

class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
end
```

Now when you execute `Profile.find(1).notifications` you should get a list of the associated notifications to that profile.

More information: [Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: Well, I have a profile table for users of the website. I want to create another table called notifications to store information such as when a user has a new private message reply. I will then use this table to alert members when someone has responded to their private message. I posted the migration code, which seems to be causing the error. I'm confused because I have other tables set up with a one-to-many this way and have never encountered this problem.